# Pdf Mrged files shell_exec() not working aws server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Pdf Merged files `shell_exec()` not working on AWS server. Any installation file is missing. Guide me or any solution.

my code:

```
$cmd = "gs -q -SDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -sOutputFile=$outputTiffFileName -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH ";

//Add each pdf file to the end of the command
foreach($fileArray as $file)
{
    $cmd .= $file." ";
}
 
//Execute the ghost script that merges multiple PDFs and saves the it in the data directory.
$response = shell_exec($cmd);
```

Any type of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is meant by "Not Working". What is the error? Have you tried executing the command directly in command line?

Comment: i am switching new aws server "gs -q -SDEVICE=pdfwrite" not working i think library file missing i cannot find which one so suggest me